# expected ')' in c function prototype

Tags: c++, c, function, arduino, arduino-ide

I have a function divided between a header and source files as follows,

In the header file:

```
uint8_t SoundEffects(uint8_t EffectType,uint8_t RecordedSample);
```

In the source file :

```
uint8_t SoundEffects(uint8_t EffectType,uint8_t RecordedSample)
{
    // some code
}
```

Generates the following error

> SoundEffects.h:7: error: expected ')' before 'EffectType'
>   SoundEffects.c:3: error: expected ')' before 'EffectType'

I've tried everything, removed variable names, changed `uint8_t` to `unsigned char`, nothing works. what is the problem?

Comment: Your problem might lie somewhere before this function... maybe you forgot a ; on the previous line?

Comment: Besides the missing extern in the header, it looks good. Divide and conquer (by commenting code), to find the actual problem.

Comment: did you include stdint.h?

Comment: @Sil functon declaration in c file doesn't need a semicolon 

and these two lines are the first thing in the header and .c file

Comment: @daouzli yes included

Comment: you can't have included `<stdint.h>` before the function definition if the two lines are the first in the file. I suggest you include both `<stdint.h>` and your custom header file.

Comment: Any chance the token `SoundEffects` has been `#define`d to something?

Comment: Did you try to compile with only what you showed (including stdint)?

Comment: [WorksForMe](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64bd23273a4032b5). Post complete code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @dlf that was the problem, please post that as an answer.

Comment: @user3633706: post **full** code, in [the form of a SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that exhibits behaviour next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you haven't `#define`d the token `SoundEffects` to something else already.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect this error when the token before 'EffectType' is not recognized as a type. In this case, 'uint8_t'. My guess would be that you need to `'include <stdint.h>'` at the top of your header file (or at least before the inclusion of your header file).